# Cannot edit page throug https but it is possible over http. 

Tags: 2010, error, https

I have a server setup with 2 WFE. 
I have a web application running on port 80, this web application is Load Balanced using a revery proxy over Https.

So i can now acces the web application on http://Server1 and on https://Portal.nl. On the https addres however i get some weird errors.

On the Https:

When i try to edit the page using Site Actions -> Edit page, i get the following error:

```
System.ArgumentException: Invalid postback or callback argument. Event validation is enabled using <pages enableEventValidation="true"/> in configuration or <%@ Page EnableEventValidation="true" %> in a page. For security purposes, this feature verifies that arguments to postback or callback events originate from the server control that originally rendered them. If the data is valid and expected, use the ClientScriptManager.RegisterForEventValidation method in order to register the postback or callback data for validation. 
bij System.Web.UI.ClientScriptManager.ValidateEvent(String uniqueId, String argument)     bij System.Web.UI.WebControls.DropDow...  f6297f6e-7ca3-4c5b-8265-d5bbc199806f
10/06/2011 10:20:43.63* w3wp.exe (0x0690)                           0x0B44  SharePoint Foundation           Runtime                         tkau    Unexpected  ...nList.LoadPostData(String postDataKey, NameValueCollection postCollection) bij System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessPostData(NameValueCollection postData, Boolean fBeforeLoad)     bij System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)  f6297f6e-7ca3-4c5b-8265-d5bbc199806f
```

When i click on Site Settings -> Navigation -> OK(or cancel) i get the same error.

i cannot edit any page on any site over this protocol.

On the Http:

I am able to edit the pages using Site Actions -> Edit page.

I can also use the navigation menu.

So the issues only occur on a specific adress, what does this mean?

Comment: What method of load balancing are you using? Is the cert installed on both servers?

Comment: @webdes03 Reverse proxy using an ISA server. The certificates are installed on both servers. I have this error only on one web application, all others (which are also load balanced ) behave normal.